# Expected value of $[(X-\mu)/\sigma]^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

I would like to ask that, there is a question asking to show that $\bar{X}$ is a minimum variance unbiased estimator of the mean $\mu$ of a normal distribution.

I am having difficulty understanding the solution,
it took log of the normal p.d.f.,
and differentiate the natural log respect to $\mu$,
and it wrote as:
hence, 
$E[(\partial ln f(x)/\partial\mu)^2=(1/\sigma^2)\times E[((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2=(1/\sigma^2)\times1$
Now I am having trouble understand why the expected value of 
$((X-\mu)/\sigma)^2$ would be 1.

Thank you very much for your reading and any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
E\left[\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right]=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\left[(X-\mu)^2\right]=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}
$$

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!!